# How to auto populate a combo box based on another table? Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Hi I am an access 2010 newbie. I would like the value of a combobox to automatically populate based on the linked ID field upon opening a form for a given record.

The value I'd like to show comes from a different table than the source table for the form, and if I change the control source specifically for the combobox, it will show the right data but not specified to the specific record displayed.

Can you help?

Comment: Since there's no specific information here, I can't really give you a specific answer.  But in general, what you would do is populate the combo in the OnLoad event of the form.  Put a line of VBA code in that event that says something like, Me.MyComboBox.RecordSource = "SELECT MyID, MyDesc FROM MyTable".  This will populate the combo with the ID and Description from the table you want.  Then just link the Combo to the ID field in the table that's driving the form.

Comment: You don't need to write VBA, you can set up the combo box's RecordSource using the GUI in the form's design mode. Set `Column Count` to `2` and `Column Width` to `0;1`. Leave `Bound Column` to `1`. Assuming you set your RecordSource to have the ID as the first field and the description as the second field and you set the `Control Source` to the linked ID field on your main table, that's all you should need.

Comment: Thanks @SunKnight0 I have set my control source to =[frm2]![field1]. Field1 is not the ID linking the two tables. Can you have two values in that expression? Where do I put the ID? Thanks!

Comment: Your control source has to be the primary table field that links to your secondary table. Not a form field and not a different field.

Comment: @SunKnight0 This is how the control source query is for the entire form: `SELECT [table1].*, [table2].[field2:], INNER JOIN [table2] ON [table1].ID = [table2].ID; `     I don't know why this doesn't work on this particular form when the same code works perfectly on other forms. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Is your table2 a whole other set of data or just the lookup values for the linked field?

Comment: @SunKnight0. It's a whole different dataset linked on the ID. Thanks!

Comment: Then there are way too many different things you could be trying to do for me to guess. You need to put a lot more information on your question.